# A consequence of the invariance of boundary

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. In Theorem 2.17, it is claimed that if $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with boundary, and $F:M \rightarrow N$ is a diffeomorphism, then $$F(\partial M)=\partial N,$$
where $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ are the boundaries of $M$ and $N$, respectively. Maybe I'm missing something, but is there a non-trivial conclusion that we can draw from this? That is:

Claim: If $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic, then $\partial M= \emptyset $ if and only if $\partial N = \emptyset$.

Does this follow, or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need the theorem to prove the claim. You can prove it with pure topology.

Comment: You are correct and you shouldn't be worried because it makes sense.

Comment: @Randall For me it is rather non-intuitive as to why this must be the case, but it seems like a very interesting fact. Thanks!